# What is the Selenium equivalent of using Google Chrome Developer Tools and clicking "Copy OuterHTML" on the outermost HTML element?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping

Previously, I was just using Google Chrome and its Developer Tools to Copy/Paste the HTML Code of a certain website.

I was just manually using Google Chrome Developer Tools and right-clicking on the outermost HTML class and pressing "Copy OuterHTML" and then I would paste that into a notepad text file and get to work on it.

But now, I want to automate this process. I want to use Selenium to grab the HTML.

I have used the following, but they do not get me the same exact result (they are missing some internal html elements and stuff) as Copying the HTML Code Manually using Google Chrome Developer Tools and my mouse:

driver.page_source,
driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.outerHTML")

Any other ideas?

**Edit:**  More details if it helps: The content which I want that is missing from my Selenium grab is likely dynamically created (and obtained from another source and updated daily)...it's not hard-coded into the website itself.

In my manual Google Developer Tools grab I can see the content that I want. In my Selenium grab, I see what I believe is Javascript, written between html "" tags.

Comment: Can you share a sample specific website that people can use to test their answers on? Judging from your comment on one of the answer, it could be dependent on the website.

Comment: It's a subscription site that involves a login, so i don't think I can.   Thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried to use [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup)? It's a scraper that grabs all the HTML from a page, and then you can select elements like with Selenium. But you can't navigate the page to trigger JS or click on buttons.

You can also try

```
driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('outerHTML')
```

Comment: I am indeed familiar with Beautiful Soup (that's what I am actually using the further parse this HTML code later on).  But anyway, I just tried using the code you recommended (driver.find_element_by_tag_name('html').get_attribute('outerHTML') and that still does not give me the exact same thing that I get using Google Chrome Developer Tools and my mouse manually.     To be more specific, it is missing a large portion of the code and information.  This code and information is probably dynamically entered into the website and changes by the minute (its sports scores) -not sure if that matters.